# Play Video Ipad Ios6

Tags: ios, xcode, video, ios6, media-player

I need to play a video when the application starts

My code works perfectly for Iphone Ipad Simulator

But not on the device physically Ipad

What's wrong??

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {

         if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

            NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Intro3" withExtension:@"mp4"];

            m_player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
            [m_player.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
            [m_player.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
            [m_player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
            [[m_player view] setFrame:[self.view bounds]];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
            [m_player play];
            [self.view addSubview:[m_player view]];

            }
            else{
               ---play video in iphone---
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The code works perfectly !!!

The problem was that the resolution of the video was too big.

Resize and worked =)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [MPMoviePlayerViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller_class/Reference/Reference.html) instead .

```
 if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

            NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Intro3" withExtension:@"mp4"];

            MPMoviePlayerViewController * controller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
            [self  presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:controller];
            [controller release];
}
```